# Sending an array with JavaScript to the next page

Tags: javascript, arrays, serialization

The combination of my methods of declaring an array, adding elements to the array and applying the method toString() does not work. Essentially I enter a certain number (between one and five) values to textvariables :  fontVorto1, fontVorto2, fontVorto3 ……… in the html-part of the document.
When I decide on leaving the remaining textelements empty, I click on a button, to assign them to an array, by way of the following function:

```
function difinNombroFv () {
    var fontVortoj = new array();
    fontVortoj[0] = document.getElementsByName("fontVorto1")[0].value;
    fontVortoj[1] = document.getElementsByName("fontVorto2")[0].value;
    fontVortoj[2] = document.getElementsByName("fontVorto3")[0].value;
……………….
```

and put them together in a string:

```
x = fontVortoj.toString();
document.getElementsByName("fontVorto")[0].value = x;
```

(the extra variable x is not needed) to enable me sending them to the next document, where I want to unserialize them with

```
$fontVortoj = unserialize($_POST["fontVorto"]);
```

I tested the method toString() by insering an alert(x), but the result was that I got for x the value of "fontVorto1" only.
I met solutions with JSON, jQuery etc., but I never used those "languages", only HTML, JavaScript, PHP.

Will my Christmas day be spoiled because of this simple problem ;>)?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I misunderstood the question to begin with.

To serialize an astray, you can use `.join()`

By default, it will give you the values, joined by commas.

To deserialize, use `.split()`

If there's a chance that there might be commas in your values, choose a more elaborate string for joining:

```
var ar = ["a", "b"];
var serialized = ar.join("|"); // "a|b"

var deserialized = serialized.split("|"); //["a", "b"]
```

The string that you use for joining and splitting can be as long as you like.

If you want to be completely covered against any values, then you need to look at `JSON.stringify()` & `JSON.parse()`. But that had browser compatibility issues.

Comment: It should be clear from  the fact that all elements are put into a form that I did already as you suggested (if I understand you well).
The function that makes the array into a string is toString and the function unserialize does the opposite. But the problem is with toString(), I guess.

Comment: @user2772060 You're right. I clearly misread the question. But I've updated my answer. I think that's what you need.

Answer (score 0):

couple of things to note:
1. var fontVortoj = new array(); . here new array() is not correct. it should be:

```
var fontVortoj = new Array();
```

1. now if you call fontVortoj.toString(), then it will convert the array and return a string with array elements separated by comma.
2. you can rebuild the array from the string in php by using "explode" function.
3. you can rebuild the array from the string in javascript by using "split" function.

Comment: Sorry to those who searched to no avail the mistakes in my code (apart from array in stead of Array). I found the error is caused by the fact that the array consisted only of one element, the other variables not being filled, because of a very cumbersome if - if else - if else etc. tree.
Let me say: just a beginner's problem !